# How to check individual output in list comprehension is not null without computing the object again

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I am trying to use a list comprehension to remove some characters from a list of strings. Hence, I use regex to remove them, but the output of the regex could be empty. Is there any way I can remove these outputs without having to make a extra loop on the array or running the regex again?

Let's say I have the following array:

```
>>> example
["a ", "    ", "", "a. &//*-_", " n", "   b   ", "*"]
```

The output I want is:

```
>>> func(example)
'a#a &//_#n#b'
```

Currently, I have this function which returns something close that I can process again to get the desired output, but I wanted to know if any solution without doing the second pass.

```
def func(example):
    pattern = "[^\w\s\&\/]"
    return "#".join(re.sub(pattern, "", unidecode(tag).lower().strip()) for tag in example)

>>> func(example)
'a###a &//_#n#b#'
```

One possibility I thought is the following, but I was wondering if this is computing again the whole processing on the string:

```
def func2(example):
    pattern = "[^\w\s\&\/]" # The pattern here is not particularly important, I just want to remove some weird characters and keep a couple
    return "#".join(re.sub(pattern, "", unidecode(tag).lower().strip()) for tag in example if re.sub(pattern, "", unidecode(tag).lower().strip()))

>>> func2(example)
'a#a &//_#n#b'
```

Comment: Your own solution is fine. Adding the `if` to the list comprehension does not add a second loop.

Comment: @YamiOmar88 it is not adding a second loop, but I was wondering if Python is computing the operation of searching the regex twice per row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This general technique works:

1. create a generator yielding the elements that are computed twice or more;
2. use this generator in a list comprehension.

In your case:

```
>>> import re
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> example = ["a ", "    ", "", "a. &//*-_", " n", "   b   ", "*"]
>>> def func3(example):
...     pattern = "[^\w\s\&\/]"
...     return "#".join(x for x in (re.sub(pattern, "", unidecode(tag).lower().strip()) for tag in example) if x)
>>> func3(example)
'a#a &//_#n#b'
```

`(re.sub(pattern, "", unidecode(tag).lower().strip()) for tag in example)` is the generator, and then you filter this generator on values that evaluate to `True`.

---

Remark: You can also use, in your specific case, the builtin `filter`:

```
>>> def func4(example):
...     pattern = "[^\w\s\&\/]"
...     return "#".join(filter(None, (re.sub(pattern, "", unidecode(tag).lower().strip()) for tag in example)))
>>> func4(example)
'a#a &//_#n#b'
```

From [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

> `filter(function, iterable)`
>   [...] If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, *all elements of iterable that are false are removed*. (emphasis mine)